# Why behaviour of git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster and git fetch origin master:mymaster is different?

Tags: git

Why behaviour of

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster
```

and

```
git fetch origin master:mymaster
```

is different?

In my observation in case of

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster
```

it was creating a remote-tracking branch "mymaster".

On the other case of

```
git fetch origin master:mymaster
```

it was creating a local branch "mymaster".

Answer (score 1):

Well `git fetch` will fast-forward your local reference, and create it if it doesn't exist. So:

```
git fetch origin master:mymaster
```

creates a branch `mymaster` locally if it doesn't exist and

```
git fetch origin +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/mymaster
```

creates a branch `remotes/origin/mymaster` locally if it doesn't exist.

The syntax being `src:dst`, where `src` is remote and `dst` local.

Comment: Heads-up for the OP: also note that `+` means "force", which makes updating succeed even if the new history to update the ref does not fully contain the old one (that is updating would not result in the so-called "fast-forward", and would be normally rejected). IOW, you have two crucial differences between your refspecs, not one.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [`gitrevisions`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html) manual page (run `git help revisions`) and look for the revision specification "`<refname>`".  Here's an excerpt from that bit of documentation:

> `<refname>`, e.g. `master`, `heads/master`, `refs/heads/master`
>
> A symbolic ref name. E.g.  `master` typically means the commit object
>   referenced by `refs/heads/master`.
>   If you happen to have both `heads/master` and
>   `tags/master`, you can explicitly say
>   `heads/master` to tell Git which one you mean.
>   When ambiguous, a `<refname>` is disambiguated by taking the first match
>   in the following rules:
>
> 1. If `$GIT_DIR/<refname>` exists, that is what you mean
>      (this is usually useful only for `HEAD`, `FETCH_HEAD`,
>      `ORIG_HEAD`, `MERGE_HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`);
> 2. otherwise, `refs/<refname>` if it exists;
> 3. otherwise, `refs/tags/<refname>` if it exists;
> 4. otherwise, `refs/heads/<refname>` if it exists;
> 5. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>` if it exists;
> 6. otherwise, `refs/remotes/<refname>/HEAD` if it exists.

So what you observed in your experiments is that when you have used unadorned `mybranch` as the target ref name, from the point of view of Git that was a *relative* ref name, and hence Git used the precedence rules to resolve it, and resolved it to `refs/heads/mymaster`.

When you used `refs/remotes/origin/mymaster`, you supplied Git with the *absolute* ref name, so there was nothing to resolve and Git used it directly.

A point of interest: it's perfectly OK to have a local branch containing a slash in its name, and it will still be relative when specified without that `refs/...` anchor.  That is, you can do `git branch foo/bar` and when you will later call `git log foo/bar` Git will use the rules above to resolve `foo/bar` into an absolute ref name (and will supposedly end up with `refs/heads/foo/bar`).